# add Cordova plugin to Meteor from local path

Tags: cordova, meteor, plugins

I have created a Cordova plugin, which I need to add to my Meteor project.  I've tried various forms of:

```
meteor add cordova:/local/path/to/plugin
```

I've also tried committing this plugin to git, so that I could try things like:

```
meteor add cordova:https://marcadonis@bitbucket.org/project/pluginname.git@1.0.0
```

to which Meteor replies:

Meteor requires either an exact version (e.g. https://marcadonis@1.0.0), a Git URL with a SHA reference, or a local path.

Of course, I'd be happy to use a local path, if I only knew how.

Is this "meteor add" command documented somewhere?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just in case anybody cares... the correct command line was:

```
meteor add cordova:plugin-id@file://path/to/plugin/project
```

where "plugin-id" seems to correspond to the id given in the header of plugin.xml.

Comment: When you change your plugin locally how do you update your local meteor app for testing?

Comment: @msj121

"Because installing plugins into a Cordova project already containing plugins can lead to indeterminate results, Meteor will remove and add back all plugins whenever a change to any of the plugins in your project is made."

https://guide.meteor.com/cordova.html#installing-plugins